# Froala and Aurelia integration

Tags: aurelia, froala

I use the Froala editor plugin inside my Aurelia app. It works pretty well.

We can pass custom parameters to the plugin in `main.ts` like below:

```
// Use the aurelia-froala-editor plugin.
aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-froala-editor', config => {
  config.options({
    toolbarInline: true
  })
});
```

Then inject the froala component inside a page:

```
<froala-editor></froala-editor>
```

But now I pass parameters directly inside my froala componont on my page:

```
<froala-editor value.two-way="post.content" config.bind="{
        toolbarInline: true,
        charCounterCount: false,
        imageUploadURL:         'http://localhost:5000/api/froala/UploadImage',
        fileUploadURL:          'http://localhost:5000/api/froala/UploadFile',
        imageManagerLoadURL:    'http://localhost:5000/api/froala/LoadImages',
        imageManagerDeleteURL:  'http://localhost:5000/api/froala/DeleteImage', 
        imageManagerDeleteMethod: 'POST'
      }" event-handlers.bind = "{
        'image.uploaded': imageUploaded,
        'image.removed': imageRemoved,
        'image.file.unlink': imageFileUnlink
      }"></froala-editor>
```

It works pretty well also.

**What did not seems to works** is mixing parameters passed in `main.ts` and in the component on a page. The component on the page seems to ignore completely parameters passed at initialization of the plugin in `main.ts`.

For example if I move the `charCounterCount` parameter from the component on my page to the initialization in `main.ts` it is simply ignored.

Comment: Is there any chance that something's overridden your global config?

Comment: @bigopon not really

Comment: From froala repo code, it seems they are not merging global config and instance based config https://github.com/froala/aurelia-froala-editor/blob/master/src/froala-editor.js Probably will need to create a PR for that. Also can you help provide a repro?

Comment: I provided a repro directly to the Froala's team.